# How to create a LiveDVD from an installed CentOS?

Tags: centos, livecd

I have an installed Centos 6.1 64 bit.

We need to create a LiveDVD from it.

The custom is that it has a few packages installed that cannot be found in repositories.

Question: how can I make a LiveDVD out of this installed CentOS? Just to boot from it and use the custom packages on them.

ps.: no, the packages couldn't be installed during a liveDVD session because of a kernel panic :)

Comment: If the answers you get are focusing primarily to the elimination of the kernel panic, it is better to leave entirely every such details of your problem, which could mislead the answerers. You want to make a LiveDVD from an installed centos, that is all.

Comment: kernel panic occurs because libc update is needed to install those custom packages.

Comment: That's why I must have a solution for creating a livedvd out of an installed centos.

Comment: In your case I would ask the kernel panic problem in a different question, without reference to the other.

Comment: maybe with livecd-creator but it's not very well documented for rpm based distros..